# Laravel does not trigger the update funktion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

My small problem is that Laravel does not trigger the update function if I click on my safe button on the edit page. The only thing that happens after clicking save is that the page is reloaded.

Here is my small snippet for the code:

edit.blade snippet:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('t_update', $transport->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
    <section id="user">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header" data-card-widget="collapse">
                    <h3 class="card-title">User</h3>
                    <div class="card-tools">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                ...
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="options">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('home') }}">
                    <i class="fas fa-times">
                    </i>
                    Cancel
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus">
                    </i>
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </form>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home/create', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'create'])->name('t_create');
Route::post('/home/create', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'store'])->name('t_save');
Route::get('/home/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'edit'])->name('t_edit');
Route::post('/home/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'update'])->name('t_update');
```

MainController (update function snippet):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            ...
        ]);

        Transport::find($id)
                ->update([
                    'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $input['lastname'],
                   ...
                ]);

        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('success','Data was successfully updated.');
    }
```

Comment: probably you are getting validation error which is not printing

Comment: check the action attribute in your form tag?

Comment: On another note, you're using the `POST` HTTP verb for a method that performs an update operation. This should really be either `PUT` or `PATCH`.

Answer (score 0):

write ->save() at the end of update function

```
Transport::find($id)
            ->update([
                'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $input['lastname'],
               ...
            ])->save();
```

Comment: You don't need to call `save` on the `update` method, it is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple,

I forgot to add an item in my validation.
So now it works fine.

thank you for your help.